# The current path, about, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and just started looking at it  installing Django 1.11.17 on my local.
But I got the below error while browsing the url.

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
^admin/ 
The current path, about, didn't match any of these.
```

I have created a Django project named website and an app named blog.
I have made the views file and urls.py as below

urls.py file in website package

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog.views import Aboutus

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about', Aboutus),
]
```

root_urlconf of setting.py file in website

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

views.py of blog

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def Aboutus(request):
    retrun HttpResponse('Woww')
```

I have spent so much time on this and browsed the answers related to this but I didn't get the solution.

I can't find out what I'm missing here so please draw my attention to the gap.

Comment: What you're describing is not possible. The error shows that in your file **website/urls.py** the only url pattern is `url(r'^admin/', ...)`, which is different than what you're saying here. Are you sure the urls.py you're showing here isn't inside your `blog` folder?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that it was in website/urls.py

Comment: You **cannot** get this error with what you're showing here.

Comment: Yeah , that's very strange. I am doing everything correctly but still I am facing this issue. Are there any other factors which can cause this issue

Comment: no, your module `website` that you point to in `ROOT_URLCONF` contains a urls.py file with a pattern for `^admin`, that's 100% certain, unless it's not using these settings you talk about. You have multiple **website** directories in various levels? Your project structure might be wrong.

Comment: I tried to write many urls but it is taking nothing except admin.

Comment: I don't have any other folder with website name